# Vagrant + Docker provider, struggling with static IP

Tags: docker, networking, vagrant, docker-network

I'm struggling with static IP assignment for Docker provider.

```
config.vm.define "dockeragent" do |dockeragent|
    dockeragent.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
        d.build_dir = "../installers/docker/"
    end
    dockeragent.vm.network :private_network, ip: "172.16.1.3"
end
```

I want my container named `dockeragent` uses `172.16.1.3` but it's using always `172.16.1.1`, my problem is that I want multiple containers, and each container must have its own IP.

Comment: Possibly just a syntax issue(?), can replace the `dockeragent.vm.network :private_network, ip: "172.16.1.3"` configuration with: `dockeragent.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.16.1.3"` then reload the VM?

Comment: Thanks @masseyb but that's not the answer and it doesn't work

Comment: Ah snap, I tried. Did some research and it doesn't look like setting the network for the container is supported, ref.: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/docker/basics.html#synced-folders-and-networking - "Private and public networks are not currently supported".